# The Rollback option is missing from post Revision page

Tags: bug, status-completed, rollbacks

A recent update to the site appears to have removed the "Rollback" option from question and answer revision history pages. I can only currently see 'source', 'edit', and 'link' options.

[image: image of available revision options, lacking 'rollback' as an option]

Comment: I don't think it has anything to do with the recent update, as just an hour ago I was able to rollback a few edits on posts.

Comment: @10Rep Notice I said "a recent update", not "the recent update". I'm not referring to any specific update that was intending to fix/change anything in particular, but obviously this was caused by *some* update to the site; it didn't just magically disappear :-)

Comment: Can you see the rollback/Rollback link on the prior revision? I did it on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65686098/revisions) earlier today and thought I had to click it on an unexpected revision.

Comment: Hmm. The goal was to remove rollback from the most recent revision (since you can't rollback to current) and, if the most recent revision itself is a rollback also remove the link from the revision it rolled back to. Looks like we missed an edge case in there somewhere, though. I think I'd expect to see a "rollback" link on the first revision of this question, for example.

Comment: @CodeCaster No, I could not -- I checked on several posts to make sure it wasn't anything to do with who posted it (e.g. me) or if it was protected, tag-only edits, etc.

Comment: In the question linked by CodeCaster, interestingly I *can* see a rollback option for 3rd and 1st revisions but not the 2nd. And here https://stackoverflow.com/posts/2906582/revisions I cannot see the option on any of the revisions cc @AdamLear Looks like there may be a couple extra edge cases (title only edits, tag only edits?) wherein the tags match a prior revision but aren't technically from the same revision.

Comment: @AdamLear I see no rollback buttons on any post or tag wiki/excerpt history I've looked at on SO, MSO, or MSE. I haven't done an exhaustive search, but it's definitely not just in one or two places.

Comment: It was me.  I did this.  A fix is in review.  I caused this when fixing [this bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/359485/235711) and the problem didn't manifest itself in testing because the bad check only failed if the current revision isn't a rollback.

Comment: @BrianNickel Just tested this and it shows/works for me again.

Comment: It's *so* nice that those links are all still in lowercase!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is fixed.

It was a bug caused by my incorrect fix to [Rollback button appears to the most recent edit revision item if it's a rollback](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/359398/rollback-button-appears-to-the-most-recent-edit-revision-item-if-its-a-rollback/359485#359485) surfaced by a different bug fix. So I'm having a real week.

Some logic was inadvertently flipped in the revisions list so that the current revision would have the "rollback" button.  It more or less looked like the following but a little more cryptic:

```
canRollback = revision != current || (current.IsRollback && !current.IsRollbackTo(revision))
```

I thought I had brought it back to the original intent when I changed it to:

```
canRollback = revision != current && (current.IsRollback && !current.IsRollbackTo(revision))
```

It certainly worked at suppressing the selection on the current revision and the one it was reverting to.  Unfortunately, it also included `current.IsRollback` and I didn't test it on posts without a rollback as the current revision. :facepalm:

The new code looks much more like:

```
canRollback = revision != current && !current.IsRollbackTo(revision)
```