# Please roll back the reintroduction of the rollback button in the post menu

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, rollbacks

A [recent fix to rollback links in the post history](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/404409/the-rollback-option-is-missing-from-post-revision-page) has [reintroduced the "[Rr]ollback" button in the post menu](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/404413/rollback-option-visible-directly-underneath-my-post-when-it-was-edited-by-others):

> [image: It is between the Edit and Delete links.]

When clicked, it shows a dialog:

> [image: Are you sure you want to rollback? All changes made by other users since your last edit will be rolled back.]

This allows a post owner to perform a two-click undo for all edits done by others since them posting or last editing said post. This is unfortunate, because:

- You can't see from this view what changed since you wrote or last edited the post. You don't know what you're going to roll back. Rollbacks should be done from the post history view, so you can pick a specific revision to roll back to.
- Users aren't familiar with this button and [are going to click it anyway](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/404413/rollback-option-visible-directly-underneath-my-post-when-it-was-edited-by-others/404414?noredirect=1#comment819094_404414), causing a burden on mods for "rollback war" auto-flags.
- Users should accept the fact that [others can edit their post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing), so there should not be an option to quickly undo any edit.

So my feature request is this: please remove this button again. It wasn't there for the past few years, I doubt its usefulness and nobody seems to have missed it.

Comment: What I dislike is that it that the button rollbacks to the last version from the post owner. If user A writes a post, then user B edits it to improve it, user C edits with undesirable changes, pressing the button reverts the changes from B. I'm as of yet undecided whether the existence of the button (not the exact operation) is helpful but this aspect of it bothers me.

Comment: In the history of bad ideas, this button is of the very variety.

Comment: The "rollback to" implementation in the post history makes so much more sense to me than this "rollback from" implementation.

Comment: This button feels like a solution in search of a problem. I can't understand what brought this about.

Comment: Or make the rollback button just take you to the post history view.

Comment: Simply remove that button. Problem solved.

Comment: For context, this change wasn't an intentional "new" feature as much as an apparent "fix." Apparently this button was [always supposed to exist, and was recently discovered and fixed to work as initially intended](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/404414/11047824). I don't however believe that this is a good change, or that it should stay.

Comment: @zcoop I know, I posted (and linked) that answer. I've added a word to the question here to clarify that the first sentence contains two links. :)

Comment: @Code I gotcha, I meant it less for you and more for anyone else that had yet to notice :) It's kinda an odd occurrence to begin with.

Comment: But it *hasn't shown up* for years, @zcoop98, so it wasn't an old occurrence. Intention aside, this is a brand new feature that is misguided and actively causing harm. It needs to be reverted.

Comment: [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65662408/revisions) of a user losing out on good edits by rolling back instead of editing (to remove the little parts they didn't like that much).

Comment: @Cody I said *odd* occurrence; that is, the circumstances surrounding it are weird, just as you describe.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The rollback button should be rolled-back now. Thank you for bringing it to our attention!

Comment: Why is the clean-up badge still available if no one can earn it?